# combine two huge excel files into one excel files

Tags: linux, excel

I have two excel files with huge data matrix.
eg.

---

`a b c d e`

---

`f g h i j`

---

`....`

and another file

`1 2 3`

---

`4 5 6`

---

`...`

I want to combine these two files into one files as below

---

`a b c d e 1 2 3`

---

`f g h i j 4 5 6`

---

`....`

how could I do? (use linux system or other excel skill?)
(p.s the matrix is too huge to open it with my microsoft office or LibreOffice) 
 ##

Comment: So what you are saying is that you have more than 524288
 rows and/or 8192 columns in each of the two 'two excel files'. I'd suggest an SQL based solution.

Comment: Yes, any suggestion would be welcomed.

Comment: do you have a csv or xls format. With csv you can try `paste -d ";" file1 file2`